# Is there a way to find recently updated passwords in KeePass?

Tags: windows, keepass

I'd like to find recently changed passwords in KeePass so that I can copy/paste them into another KeePass repository. I see that the date updated is stored as the version in the History tab, but I don't see a way to sort entries by this value. I'm thinking that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### KeePass 2.xx

1. menu **View** > **Grouping by Entry List** > **Off**
2. menu **View** > **Show Entries of Subgroups** → set checked
   OR to view all entries one time only, go menu **View** > **Show all**
3. menu **View** > **Configure Columns...** → place check mark at **Last Modification Time** and confirm
4. click the root item of your KeePass folder tree
5. click header of **Last Modification Time** column to get all your passwords sorted by date/time

You can now see entries from your entire database sorted by **Last Modification Time**.

Comment: Awesome. On mine (v. 2.32 on Ubuntu 16.04), the "Show all" is not under "View", rather it is "Edit > Show All Entries" - to save anyone else those milliseconds it takes to look in the other menus.

Answer (score 5):

### KeePass 2.42

Main menu *Find* > *Last Modified Entries...*.

The most recent modifications are on top. It looks like there's the **whole log of changes in the opened database since it has been created**. In my case, it goes back to the year 2006.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution is:

1. Click "EDIT"
2. Click "SHOW ENTRIES"
3. Finally click "LAST MODIFIED ENTRIES"

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: The "LAST MODIFIED ENTRIES" feature has been recently added to KeePass, so the procedure above can be used to get all the "passwords recently updated". Just click Edit --> Show Entries --> Last modified entries to get the list of entries with references to the "Last update date". You'll get a nice dialog with the following information: group | Entry name | Username | Date of last update

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://keepass.info/help/v2/sync.html
You may be able to automate synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You can use KeePass build-in synchronization. To manually synchronize with file go to menu **File** > **Synchronize** > **Synchronize with File**. More about synchronization: http://keepass.info/help/v2/sync.html

Comment: Maybe you can explain how this can be used to find recently updated passwords (what was asked).

Comment: Question was about way how-to manually copy-paste new passwords from one repository to another. There is future that allow synchronise few repositories in several ways, or simply to have passwords synchronised automatically without need of manual copying.

Answer (score 0):

### KeePass 1.xx

The other answers here appeared to be for KeePass version 2. This answer should work for Version 1 on Windows.

I am not sure why this works, but here is what I did:

1. Ensure the column for "last modification time" is enabled
2. Somewhere in the left (groups) column, right click
3. Click `Rearrange` > `Sort Group List`
4. Voila, the right side is sorted by last modification date

(again, this doesn't make much sense, but it works... and you *still* cannot click the column header to reverse sort it... strange.)

**UPDATE:**
This appears to only show the second-to-latest update at the top - again, not sure why. But if your top entry is an entry in the "backup" group, it should still give you a good idea what the last thing changed was... i.e. go look at the current entry for the one listed as last changed in the top "backup" entry.